# How do I change touchpad behavior with libinput running under wayland

Tags: fedora, touchpad, wayland, libinput

The typical method of changing trackpad behavior is to edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/<some number>-synaptics.conf`.

I'm running Fedora 25 running GNOME 3.22 and which uses Wayland by default, not X, so there is no `<some number>-synaptics.conf` file in there, just this:

```
00-keyboard.conf
```

So how do you change the trackpad behavior in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't, at least not in GNOME. KDE or other distros offer a few more knobs, but most of the libinput behavior is not user-configurable the way it is in Xorg. If you don't like the behavior, file a bug: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Wayland